# Generate a working day sequence in R

Tags: r, time, time-series, sequence

I want to generate a working week / working day sequence (Monday-Friday; 8am - 5pm) in R. However I only figured out how to extract a working week (Monday-Friday) with 24 hours.

```
library(timeDate)
start <- as.POSIXct("2010-01-01")
interval <- 60
seq_1 <- as.timeDate(seq(from=start, by=interval*60, length.out = 200))

seq_2 <- seq_1[isWeekday(seq_1)]; seq_2
dayOfWeek(seq_2)
```

Is there a similar function which can extract only working hours? Thanks

Comment: what are you expecting to obtain from your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use function format to obtain hours

```
seq_2[as.numeric(format(seq_2,'%H')) %in% 8:15 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Select weekdays and then repeat with frequency equal to the desired hours. I'm afraid I missed your 8 o;clock start and used the phrase "9 to 5" as my guide:

```
twoyears <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by='day', length.out=365*2)
twoworkyrs <- twoyears[isWeekday(twoyears, wday = 1:5)]
twoworkyrs[ 1:10]
# [1] "2010-01-01" "2010-01-04" "2010-01-05" "2010-01-06" "2010-01-07" "2010-01-08"
# [7] "2010-01-11" "2010-01-12" "2010-01-13" "2010-01-14"
workhours <- as.POSIXct( as.numeric(rep(twoworkyrs, each=9))*24*3600 + # weekdays
                         (9:17)*3600 , n                            # working hours
        origin="1970-01-01", tz="America/LosAngeles")
#----- First two weeks ----------------
> workhours[1:90]
 [1] "2010-01-01 09:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 10:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 11:00:00 UTC"
 [4] "2010-01-01 12:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 13:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 14:00:00 UTC"
 [7] "2010-01-01 15:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 16:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-01 17:00:00 UTC"
[10] "2010-01-04 09:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 10:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 11:00:00 UTC"
[13] "2010-01-04 12:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 13:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 14:00:00 UTC"
[16] "2010-01-04 15:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 16:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-04 17:00:00 UTC"
[19] "2010-01-05 09:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 10:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 11:00:00 UTC"
[22] "2010-01-05 12:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 13:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 14:00:00 UTC"
[25] "2010-01-05 15:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 16:00:00 UTC" "2010-01-05 17:00:00 UTC"
[snipped
```

I must admit that timezone conversions are one of my weakest suits.